# Qt error: LNK1181: cannot open input file 'debug\main.obj'

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Qt creator was working well, but suddenly shows a problem `error: LNK1181: cannot open input file 'debug\main.obj'`.
This problem shows always with any type of application either `GUI` or `console`.
I've uninstall the Qt, and install again, but the problem still exists.
I did not do anything in the Qt creator settings, I left the default settings.

The following application is simple console application occur the same problem in it.

```
//main.cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Note**: I'm using Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, OpenGL).

Comment: This is most likely caused by an error in the *project* settings. Source files (\*.cpp) are compiled into object files (\*.o) which are then all linked together. Somehow the linker is failing to find the object files compiled from your source files. I can tell it is looking into debug\, but they are being stored somewhere else. Do you have write permissions to that directory?

Comment: @brunocodutra: I'm using `Windows 7 32bit`.

Comment: what I said still applies for Windows, but unfortunately I'm not very familiar with it, specially when it comes to programing.

Comment: So your using the qt addin for visual studio 2010 on windows 7?

Answer (score 23):

This problem also occurs if the path of your project (name of any folder) contains a white space.

Comment: How do you fix it if you don't have the option to build from a different directory?

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck If you cannot change the project path maybe you can rewrite builds steps and put the project path in qoutes? Or write a script that builds the project without the use of QtCreator? Other than that I have no idea.

Comment: Yeah, if it was just a matter of building, I would do that, but I actually like to use Qt Creator while debugging; the prospect of constantly changing stuff around, even when automated, sounds pretty aggravating. I tried adding quotes around my shadow build location as well as my project folder location, but it never fixed the issue. I also couldn't find anyone who has found a solution to this on or off the StackExchange.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck I am afraid that Qt Creaor simply does not support spaces in the project path. You are explicitly told to remove spaces when creating new project. Sorry

Comment: No need to apologize! :) This is one of the few cases where Visual Studio's default project paths with white space already included makes Qt Creator seem quite immature for such a basic thing.

Comment: It looks like the culprit here is actually JOM. If you go to "Projects" section of Qt Creator in the "Build" tab, you can see that QMAKE adds quotes around project files it runs against, but JOM does not. Furthermore, there does not appear to be a way to inject quotes in those fields without breaking Qt's ability to detect the directory. I think I found a way to actually fix this, but I need to test some more.

Comment: w00t! ^_^ I found a fix!

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck Thank you for sharing this. I will keep this in mind :)

Answer (score 9):

This problem occurs also if you have in the .pro or .pri files something like:

> HEADERS += \ \

**or**

> SOURCES += \ \

Answer (score 3):

Okay, we finally have a real answer for this generalized problem instead of the OP's typo problem if that didn't unblock you either.

**Actual Problem** (black-box perspective): The "Build directory" auto-filled entry breaks for projects inside whitespace directories. Qt Creator actually prohibits you and tells you not to use whitespace when making new Projects. You can still close a new project and re-name it to add whitespace, and Qt Creator will handle it gracefully. If you copy the build directory, even with whitespace in it, and paste that into the field replacing the broken auto-generated path (mine was using relative paths) then JOM will start working correctly, as QMake does not generate any errors. I can't speak for other Make tools.

1. Make or clone down your project with whitespace
2. Load it in Qt Creator
3. Run QMAKE
4. Select the "Project" button on the left-hand side
5. Make sure you're in the "Build" tab
6. Select "Browse", and then re-select the shadow directory QMAKE made

**That should unblock you if it wasn't a simple issue for deleting the old QMAKE-generated folders**, which is the most common problem people face with this specific error while developing within Qt Creator.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem has been solved.**

The cause of the problem was when creating a new project (`GUI` or `Console`), all source files that belong to this new project take a wrong extension ex: `main.cp`, but the correct extension is supposed to be ex: `main.cpp`.
And when changing all the source files extension from `.cp` to `.cpp` worked fine.

Or change the default source file extension from **[Tools -> Option -> C++]**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the error because of this:

```
HEADERS += \ \
    $$PWD/QOakTreeViewRecursiveModel.h
```

instead of:

```
HEADERS += \
    $$PWD/QOakTreeViewRecursiveModel.h
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

1. Close the Qt Creator
2. Delete the [filename].pro.user file in your project directory
3. Open the project again and let Qt configure itself

Generally whenever I encounter an error like this, this is one of the first things I do as it solves a lot of problems with Qt.

**Edit**: This will of course reset your project build location.

Comment: this is not a proper way to solve this & still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

hmm If I remember correctly when I faced this kind of problems using your similar setup (QtCreator and Windows) running QMAKE & rebuilding the project again helped me solve this linker errors.

Comment: Thanks, I did everything you said, but did not solve the problem, but after what I did what previously explained, the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Run `Clean` and `qMake` and `rebuild`.
I has like this problem and this helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing the big path and space names in the directories.
Try to create a folder in C:/ and copy or clone the project in this folder.
Remove all builder folders and configure the project again.
That solved it for me.