# Using two different header file extensions in Qt Creator (Windows)

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, windows-7-x64

I have the following error if I want to build a project: `LNK1181: cannot open input file "release\main.obj"`.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604302/qt-error-lnk1181-cannot-open-input-file-debug-main-obj) the problem seems to be that I want to include `.h` header files and `.hpp` header files in one Qt project. This is more or less necessary, because we are using **opencv**.

Here is the `.pro`-file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-10-18T11:37:00
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui datavisualization charts

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Qt_OpenCV_Test
TEMPLATE = app
win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += C:\\OpenCV-3.1.0\\opencv\\build\\include

    LIBS += -LC:\\OpenCV-3.1.0\\mybuild\\lib\\Debug \
        -lopencv_calib3d310d \
        -lopencv_core310d \
        -lopencv_features2d310d \
        -lopencv_flann310d \
        -lopencv_highgui310d \
        -lopencv_imgcodecs310d \
        -lopencv_imgproc310d \
        -lopencv_ml310d \
        -lopencv_objdetect310d \
        -lopencv_photo310d \
        -lopencv_shape310d \
        -lopencv_stitching310d \
        -lopencv_superres310d \
        -lopencv_ts310d \
        -lopencv_video310d \
        -lopencv_videoio310d \
        -lopencv_videostab310d \

}
unix {
    CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
    PKGCONFIG += opencv
    LIBS += -L/usr/include/opencv
    LIBS += -L"$$PWD/sqlite3" -lsqlite3
}

SOURCES +=  src/main.cpp \
            src/Utils/utils.cpp \
            src/Utils/db_manager.cpp \
            src/Gui/mainwindow.cpp \
            src/Gui/cqtopencvviewergl.cpp \
            src/Gui/DataVisualization/simpledatavisualization.cpp \
            src/Gui/DataVisualization/surfacedatavisualization.cpp \
            src/Gui/DataVisualization/datavisualization.cpp \
            src/OpenCV/cv_manager.cpp \
            src/OpenCV/cv_camera.cpp \

HEADERS  += include/Utils/utils.h \
            include/Utils/containers.h \
            include/Utils/db_manager.h \
            include/Gui/mainwindow.h \
            include/Gui/cqtopencvviewergl.h \
            include/Gui/DataVisualization/simpledatavisualization.h \
            include/Gui/DataVisualization/surfacedatavisualization.h \
            include/Gui/DataVisualization/datavisualization.h \
            include/OpenCV/cv_manager.h \
            include/OpenCV/cv_camera.h \

FORMS    += src/Gui_Ui/mainwindow.ui \
            src/Gui_Ui/simpledatavisualization.ui \
            src/Gui_Ui/surfacedatavisualization.ui

DISTFILES += \
    CMakeLists.txt
```

And here is the output from the compiler:

```
    13:35:24: Führe Schritte für Projekt Stp aus...
13:35:24: Starte "C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" clean
    C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release clean
    del release\moc_mainwindow.cpp release\moc_cqtopencvviewergl.cpp release\moc_simpledatavisualization.cpp release\moc_surfacedatavisualization.cpp
F:\Downloads\ProjektBuild\release\moc_mainwindow.cpp konnte nicht gefunden werden
    del ui_mainwindow.h ui_simpledatavisualization.h ui_surfacedatavisualization.h
F:\Downloads\ProjektBuild\ui_mainwindow.h konnte nicht gefunden werden
    del release\main.obj release\utils.obj release\db_manager.obj release\mainwindow.obj release\cqtopencvviewergl.obj release\simpledatavisualization.obj release\surfacedatavisualization.obj release\datavisualization.obj release\cv_manager.obj release\cv_camera.obj release\moc_mainwindow.obj release\moc_cqtopencvviewergl.obj release\moc_simpledatavisualization.obj release\moc_surfacedatavisualization.obj
F:\Downloads\ProjektBuild\release\main.obj konnte nicht gefunden werden
    del release\Qt_OpenCV_Test.exp
F:\Downloads\ProjektBuild\release\Qt_OpenCV_Test.exp konnte nicht gefunden werden
    C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug clean
    del debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp debug\moc_cqtopencvviewergl.cpp debug\moc_simpledatavisualization.cpp debug\moc_surfacedatavisualization.cpp
    del ui_mainwindow.h ui_simpledatavisualization.h ui_surfacedatavisualization.h
    del debug\main.obj debug\utils.obj debug\db_manager.obj debug\mainwindow.obj debug\cqtopencvviewergl.obj debug\simpledatavisualization.obj debug\surfacedatavisualization.obj debug\datavisualization.obj debug\cv_manager.obj debug\cv_camera.obj debug\moc_mainwindow.obj debug\moc_cqtopencvviewergl.obj debug\moc_simpledatavisualization.obj debug\moc_surfacedatavisualization.obj
    del debug\Qt_OpenCV_Test.exp debug\Qt_OpenCV_Test.ilk debug\Qt_OpenCV_Test.idb
F:\Downloads\ProjektBuild\debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp konnte nicht gefunden werden
F:\Downloads\ProjektBuild\ui_mainwindow.h konnte nicht gefunden werden
F:\Downloads\ProjektBuild\debug\main.obj konnte nicht gefunden werden
F:\Downloads\ProjektBuild\debug\Qt_OpenCV_Test.exp konnte nicht gefunden werden
    del Qt_OpenCV_Test.exp
F:\Downloads\ProjektBuild\Qt_OpenCV_Test.exp konnte nicht gefunden werden
13:35:24: Der Prozess "C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" wurde normal beendet.
13:35:24: Unveränderte Konfiguration, qmake-Schritt wird übersprungen.
13:35:24: Starte "C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release
    C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\bin\uic.exe "..\..\Dropbox\Studium\5. Semester\Systemtechnikprojekt\StpGIT\main\src\Gui_Ui\mainwindow.ui" -o ui_mainwindow.h
    C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\bin\uic.exe "..\..\Dropbox\Studium\5. Semester\Systemtechnikprojekt\StpGIT\main\src\Gui_Ui\simpledatavisualization.ui" -o ui_simpledatavisualization.h
    C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\bin\uic.exe "..\..\Dropbox\Studium\5. Semester\Systemtechnikprojekt\StpGIT\main\src\Gui_Ui\surfacedatavisualization.ui" -o ui_surfacedatavisualization.h
    C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_DATAVISUALIZATION_LIB -DQT_CHARTS_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -D_MSC_VER=1900 -D_WIN32 -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/mkspecs/win32-msvc2015 -I"F:/Dropbox/Studium/5. Semester/Systemtechnikprojekt/StpGIT/main" -IC:/OpenCV-3.1.0/opencv/build/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtDataVisualization -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtCharts -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtCore -I. "..\..\Dropbox\Studium\5. Semester\Systemtechnikprojekt\StpGIT\main\include\Gui\mainwindow.h" -o release\moc_mainwindow.cpp
    C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_DATAVISUALIZATION_LIB -DQT_CHARTS_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -D_MSC_VER=1900 -D_WIN32 -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/mkspecs/win32-msvc2015 -I"F:/Dropbox/Studium/5. Semester/Systemtechnikprojekt/StpGIT/main" -IC:/OpenCV-3.1.0/opencv/build/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtDataVisualization -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtCharts -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtCore -I. "..\..\Dropbox\Studium\5. Semester\Systemtechnikprojekt\StpGIT\main\include\Gui\cqtopencvviewergl.h" -o release\moc_cqtopencvviewergl.cpp
    C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_DATAVISUALIZATION_LIB -DQT_CHARTS_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -D_MSC_VER=1900 -D_WIN32 -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/mkspecs/win32-msvc2015 -I"F:/Dropbox/Studium/5. Semester/Systemtechnikprojekt/StpGIT/main" -IC:/OpenCV-3.1.0/opencv/build/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtDataVisualization -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtCharts -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtCore -I. "..\..\Dropbox\Studium\5. Semester\Systemtechnikprojekt\StpGIT\main\include\Gui\DataVisualization\simpledatavisualization.h" -o release\moc_simpledatavisualization.cpp
    C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_DATAVISUALIZATION_LIB -DQT_CHARTS_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -D_MSC_VER=1900 -D_WIN32 -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/mkspecs/win32-msvc2015 -I"F:/Dropbox/Studium/5. Semester/Systemtechnikprojekt/StpGIT/main" -IC:/OpenCV-3.1.0/opencv/build/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtDataVisualization -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtCharts -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/msvc2015/include/QtCore -I. "..\..\Dropbox\Studium\5. Semester\Systemtechnikprojekt\StpGIT\main\include\Gui\DataVisualization\surfacedatavisualization.h" -o release\moc_surfacedatavisualization.cpp
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -O2 -MD -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_DATAVISUALIZATION_LIB -DQT_CHARTS_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -I"..\..\Dropbox\Studium\5. Semester\Systemtechnikprojekt\StpGIT\main" -I. -IC:\OpenCV-3.1.0\opencv\build\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtDataVisualization -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtCharts -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtCore -Irelease -I. -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015 -Forelease\ @C:\Users\SUITWO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_mainwindow.obj.7008.452.jom
moc_mainwindow.cpp
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -O2 -MD -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_DATAVISUALIZATION_LIB -DQT_CHARTS_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -I"..\..\Dropbox\Studium\5. Semester\Systemtechnikprojekt\StpGIT\main" -I. -IC:\OpenCV-3.1.0\opencv\build\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtDataVisualization -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtCharts -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtCore -Irelease -I. -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015 -Forelease\ @C:\Users\SUITWO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_simpledatavisualization.obj.7008.530.jom
moc_simpledatavisualization.cpp
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -O2 -MD -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_DATAVISUALIZATION_LIB -DQT_CHARTS_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -I"..\..\Dropbox\Studium\5. Semester\Systemtechnikprojekt\StpGIT\main" -I. -IC:\OpenCV-3.1.0\opencv\build\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtDataVisualization -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtCharts -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtCore -Irelease -I. -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015 -Forelease\ @C:\Users\SUITWO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_cqtopencvviewergl.obj.7008.546.jom
moc_cqtopencvviewergl.cpp
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -O2 -MD -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_DATAVISUALIZATION_LIB -DQT_CHARTS_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -I"..\..\Dropbox\Studium\5. Semester\Systemtechnikprojekt\StpGIT\main" -I. -IC:\OpenCV-3.1.0\opencv\build\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtDataVisualization -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtCharts -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\include\QtCore -Irelease -I. -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015 -Forelease\ @C:\Users\SUITWO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_surfacedatavisualization.obj.7008.982.jom
moc_surfacedatavisualization.cpp
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:release\Qt_OpenCV_Test.exe @C:\Users\SUITWO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Qt_OpenCV_Test.exe.7008.4009.jom
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: Eingabedatei "release\main.obj" kann nicht geöffnet werden.
jom: F:\Downloads\ProjektBuild\Makefile.Release [release\Qt_OpenCV_Test.exe] Error 1181
jom: F:\Downloads\ProjektBuild\Makefile [release] Error 2
13:35:28: Der Prozess "C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" wurde mit dem Rückgabewert 2 beendet.
Fehler beim Erstellen/Deployment des Projekts Stp (Kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 MSVC2015 32bit)
Bei der Ausführung von Schritt "Make"
13:35:28: Verstrichene Zeit: 00:04.
```

Is it possible to use two different header file extensions in one Qt project?

How can I fix this problem ?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: I don't think the other question/answer is related. Extension on the source files can lead to the wrong compiler being invoked, e.g. a `.c` extension will get the C compiler run instead of the C++ compiler, which is likely what happened in the other person's case.
Check that `main.cpp` is in your `SOURCES` variable, also check the compile output and see if it actually got compiled

Comment: @KevinKrammer Yes it is, I added the `.pro`-file

Comment: That looks good. Any hint on the compile output tab regarding compilation of `main.cpp`?

Comment: @KevinKrammer I added the compiler output. No mention of `main.cpp`.

Comment: Is that for a clean build? It doesn't seem to contain any compiler invocations

Comment: @KevinKrammer I added the whole compiler output of a clean build!

Comment: Ok, this is bad, it does not try to compile any of the source files. It correctly processes the forms, four headers which seem to have `Q_OBJECT` markers in them and then compiles the four resulting C++ files.
Can you try to remove the trailing `\` after the last entry of `SOURCES`?
If that doesn't help, try a project directory without spaces in dir names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. I usde a project directory path without spaces.