# LNK1181: cannot open input file 'release\main.obj' - when rebuilding QT application

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt5.8

I am a newbie to the QT application. I got some QT based project from my vendor. The sample application is built on QT 5.8.0 msvc2013 32 bit/64 bit, But I don't have msvc 2013 instead I have msvc 2017 installed on my pc. When Rebuilding (after Qmake) the received code I am getting below issue.

### Can anyone help me out to get rid of this issue also Looking forward to get your advise on configuring the Qtcreator project and build setting.

*error: LNK1181: cannot open input file 'release\main.obj'.
The kit Desktop Qt 5.8.0 MSVC2017 64bit has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"*

The Project.Pro file code,

```
    #-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-09-21T09:39:10
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += Win64
#CONFIG += console

Win64 {
    TARGET_NAME = umxPrevViewer64
} else {
    TARGET_NAME = umxPrevViewer
}

TEMPLATE = app


FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
            formmain.ui \
            formpreview.ui \
            formenroll.ui \
            formrecog.ui

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
#    DESTDIR = build/debug
    CMI_DEBUG = d
} else {
#    DESTDIR = build/release
    CMI_DEBUG =
}

message("release_build_mode ")
win32-msvc2017 {
    message("win32-msvc2017 ")

    Win64 {
        LIBS += -L"../lib/PocoWin64" \
            -lPocoFoundation$${CMI_DEBUG} \
            -lPocoXML$${CMI_DEBUG} \
            -lPocoUtil$${CMI_DEBUG} \
            -lPocoNet$${CMI_DEBUG} \
            -lPocoJSON$${CMI_DEBUG}
    } else {
       LIBS += -L"../lib/PocoWin" \
            -lPocoFoundation$${CMI_DEBUG} \
            -lPocoXML$${CMI_DEBUG} \
            -lPocoUtil$${CMI_DEBUG} \
            -lPocoNet$${CMI_DEBUG} \
            -lPocoJSON$${CMI_DEBUG}
    }

    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
 message("win32-msvc2017 32")
        Win64 {
            DESTDIR = "..\\bin\\windows\\debug64\\"
            LIBS += "..\\bin\\windows\\debug64\\umxPrevLib64d.lib"
        } else {
            DESTDIR = "..\\bin\\windows\\debug\\"
            LIBS += "..\\bin\\windows\\debug\\umxPrevLibd.lib"
        }
    } else { message("win32-msvc2017 64")
        Win64 {
            DESTDIR = "..\\bin\\windows\\release64\\"
            LIBS += "..\\bin\\windows\\release64\\umxPrevLib64.lib"
        } else {
            DESTDIR = "..\\bin\\windows\\release\\"
            LIBS += "..\\bin\\windows\\release\\umxPrevLib.lib"
        }
    }

    TARGET = $${TARGET_NAME}


    CMI_HOME = "../include/umxPrevLib"
    POCO_HOME = "../include"
}  

#INCLUDEPATH += $${POCO_HOME}
INCLUDEPATH += ../include

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp \
    formmain.cpp \
    formpreview.cpp \
    formenroll.cpp \
    formrecog.cpp \
    restsend.cpp \
    restrecv/handler/LockRequestHandlerM.cpp \
    restrecv/handler/ControlRequestHandlerM.cpp \
    restrecv/restrecvrun.cpp \
    restrecv/restrecv.cpp \
    rs232.c

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    ../include/umxPrevLib/requestdatatype.h \
    ../include/umxPrevLib/umxprevlib.hpp \
    formmain.h \
    global.h \
    formpreview.h \
    formenroll.h \
    formrecog.h \
    restsend.h \
    restrecv/HTTPRequestHandlerFactory.h \
    restrecv/Locker.h \
    restrecv/handler/HTTPRequestVerbHandlerM.h \
    restrecv/handler/LockRequestHandlerM.h \
    restrecv/handler/ControlRequestHandlerM.h \
    restrecv/restrecvrun.h \
    restrecv/restrecv.h \
    rs232.h


RESOURCES += \
    images.qrc
```

The below is my project Build setting.
[image]

The below is my Kit setting,

[image]

Comment: You should not set DESTDIR as you might be conflicting with the shadow build.

Something strange here, you seem to be willing to link a library that has the same name as your application. Is that the case ?

Comment: Yes, The exe name and lib name are not same , The lib name is "umxPrevLib.dll" and exe name is "umxPrevViewer.exe"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt error: LNK1181: cannot open input file 'debug\main.obj'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604302/qt-error-lnk1181-cannot-open-input-file-debug-main-obj)